# "time" is not a member of "std"

Tags: c++, compilation, std

An error showed up saying "time" is not a member of "std" for the sentence:

```
std::srand(std::time(0));
```

`<ctime>` and `<cstdlib>` already included. And the compiler is TDM-GCC MinGW.

I met this error several times and I still can't figure out the reasons.

Comment: Post a [mcve] reproducing the error as required here please.

Comment: Unable to reproduce: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/995733500bfdc6f3

Comment: You may indicate what is your compiler release and what options you have selected

Comment: @Damien the compiler is TDM-GCC MinGW

Comment: You may edit the question, indicating gcc version. I have MinGW at home. When back I will test it if it is still useful

Comment: What does `g++ --version` output?

Comment: I made the same test as eerorika with MinGW gcc 6.3.0.1 -> no problem. @Meng if your version is older you can update it. If your problem is still there, please post the exact complete example

Answer (score 1):

This is because `time(2)` is a [C standard library function](https://linux.die.net/man/2/time), not a C++ standard library function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto t = time(nullptr);
    std::srand(t);
    std::cout << t << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: eerorica (clang) and I (gcc) made the test with std::time(0), as the PO. We were unable to reproduce the problem

Comment: And it works with those compilers on my system too. However if you go back to an old enough version you can run into this error, and `time(2)` does still exist outside `std` namespace. There are two other things wrong with that code, using `0` instead of `nullptr` as the argument to `time()`, and passing the result of `time()` to `std::srand()`, but neither should have cause the error.